# Firefox's bookmark dropdown menus no longer display relative scroll position of last selected bookmark

Tags: firefox, macos, bookmarks

**Firefox 112.0

OSX 11.7.6**

I use Firefox's 'bookmark toolbar' to organize my regularly accessed bookmarks in folders. Some of the folders contain enough bookmarks in each folder that I have to scroll through the dropdown menu to reach some of them. A nice feature which was working until recently was that Firefox would remember and restore the last scroll position of a particular folder so that I did not have to "rescroll" to the last position to select an adjacent bookmark. It no longer does this and instead requires that I scroll down from the top of a folder dropdown each time. It's a subtle and hard to describe behavior but it was a very nice feature.

I have not knowingly changed any settings and am wondering if this feature was removed or if there is some preference I can clear to restore this behavior. I have quit and relaunched Firefox numerous times, etc. Any tips?